# how do I apply MINUS on listagg and substr?

Tags: oracle

I have a listagg function applied to table 1 that I want to compare with a substring returned in another query.

It is returning all the elements present in the first query.

I want to fetch such records which are present in the first query(listagg) but not in second (substr).

Comment: Could you provide sample data for both tables, that illustrates what you want to happen?

Comment: @trincot: Hi, so first query is returning multiple comma separated values, while the second query returns just a single record. I want to fetch all the elements of first query apart from that one element which is present in the second.

**Table 1 output:**
29972932,29973396,29976915,29969987,29976961


**Table 2 output:**
29972932

Comment: So you don't want to filter rows, but filter comma-separated values? `MINUS` is for filtering rows.

Comment: @APC: True, I am just flip-flopping from one approach to the other. I have added the sample on my previous comment.
 I want to fetch all the elements of first query apart from that one element which is present in the second. Table 1 output: 29972932,29973396,29976915,29969987,29976961 Table 2 output:29972932 
I want to fetch only 29973396,29976915,29969987,29976961 in a new column

Comment: That sample (presumably) represents `col` but doesn't include values for the `col2` used in your posted code. So it's not enough for us to understand your problem.

Comment: @APC: Updated the sample.

Comment: @APC: Yes, I edited the question with the query I am using for the better understanding. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2):

MINUS operates on the projection of each sub-query. Because you're generating aggregated strings in the sub-queries you have different strings, so the MINUS eliminates nothing.

What you need to do is apply the MINUS to individual values, then LISTAGG() the resulting set. Except that you use `col2` for the ordering, so MINUS is probably not the best solution.

Maybe this is what you need:

```
select listagg(col,',') within group (order by col2 desc) as name 
from table1
where table1.col not in
    ( select table2.col 
      from table2 )
```